# What's the meaning of "turn up" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following is a passage from [this](http://www.salon.com/2013/12/04/dont_panic_about_applebees_tablets_at_tables_wont_destroy_human_interaction/) article:

> Tablets have been **turning up** steadily at restaurants over the past few years, and not just in places with a triple chocolate meltdown-centric bill of fare. Two years ago, Chicago Cut Steakhouse introduced an app to “allow our customers to search by varietal, vintage, price and more,” and servers provide iPads for patrons to browse it. Similarly, Celebrity Cruises uses iPad menus for its on-board guests.

Does *turn up* referred to above mean definition #110h from [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/turn?s=t):?

> to come to notice; be seen.

Comment: I think your pick is quite right. I understand this *turn up* as *to appear*, *to show up*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with 110f from that list: *To appear; arrive*.

Meaning 110h would imply that they were hidden and are just now being noticed, but really they were not there previously and now are being placed.